# Control bits forbidden combination

Tags: tcp

What are the control bits forbidden sequences in a segment? Only SYN + FIN and SYN + URG come as candidates to my mind, do you know others? Is there somewhere a list of these?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should consult the source. [RFC 793, TRANSMISSION CONTROL PROTOCOL](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793) defines and describes TCP, and [Section 3.9, Event Processing](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#section-3.9) discusses what happens during processing, step-by-step.

There is no simple table of invalid combinations in the RFC, but you are walked step-by-step through what happens in each state when different events happen, including receiving segments with control flags set. If you understand how TCP processes received segments, you could create a table, but that is really beside the point: processing as the RFC specifies will result in invalid combinations being handled correctly as errors.

Comment: I know there is no simple table in the RFC. Point is, I would like to track if these combinations are actually treated as errors in an implementation. I just want to know if someone already had this table, even from a less reliable source than IETF in case I miss some combinations while reading the RFC.

Comment: A simple Google search turns up sites which have such a list, but resource recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: Note that it is allowed to send data along with the SYN packet. If the sender knows that this will be the last packet, that would be a use case for SYN+FIN, which would come in handy for a RESTful web service -- client sends SYN+FIN with data, server responds with SYN+ACK+FIN and data, client sends ACK.